# terminal line height for nice "tree" ascii art display

Tags: gnome-terminal, tree

Applications like `tree` uses some special characters to display ascii art. Unfortunately, gnome-terminal has a line height higher than the characters, giving spaces between the lines. See the screenshot:

[image: tree display]

Is there a way to get rid space between the lines and have a nicer tree display?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem with tee using bash on Ubuntu 12.10 with the default system terminal. The lines appear joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was on a Ubuntu 12.04 system. Trying it on 12.10 worked - the lines are joined. Thanks Mowgli for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference: it got "fixed" in Ubuntu 12.10 because gnome-terminal (well, actually vte) no longer takes these line drawing characters from the font, but has a special code to draw them manually instead.